# how to open vue-router in modal

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'v been trying to get router-view works in a modal( like twitter ). any one could help?

this is maybe a way to achive that but I'm not sure if is it the right way

```js
const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/other',
      components: {
        default: Foo,
        modal: Bar,
      }
    }
  ]
})

new Vue({
 router,
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
   
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>Named Views</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <router-link to="/">/</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link to="/other">/other</router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <router-view class="view one"></router-view>
  <router-view class="view two" name="modal"></router-view>
</div>
```

how to use modal router-view to be opened inside modal?

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is define `Bar` as an open modal.
This way when you navigate to `other` the modal is shown and when you navigate away it gets hidden.